# Upload and download button doesn't work for the third and fourth column of my database

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am developing a windows form application in C# using Microsoft visual studio 2010. I have a download and upload button for attaching files to my local database(grid view). I have no problem with my 2nd column cells. But when comes uploading attachment to the third and fourth column cells i am unable to attach and download files. What do you think? Do i need a separate buttons for these columns too. Or can you please tell me how to upload and download files using the same buttons present in my form.

I am able to attach files to the column 3rd and 4th, please see the link for the snap shot. http://i60.tinypic.com/xbe0bo.jpg

[image: snapshot]

**Codes are below**

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;
 using System.IO;



  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

   {

    // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cncDataSet1.CncInfo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.

    this.cncInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.cncDataSet1.CncInfo);

    timer1.Start();

   }

private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    try

    {

        //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.

        //make sure user select only single cell

        if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 1)

        {

            UploadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);

        }

        else if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1].ColumnIndex == 2)

        {

            UploadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1]);

        }

        else if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].ColumnIndex == 3)

        {

            UploadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2]);

        }

        else

            MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }

    catch (Exception ex)

    {

        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

    }

}



private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.

    //make sure user select only single cell

    //and the cell have a value in it

    if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 &&     cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value != null)

    {

        DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);

    }

    else if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1].ColumnIndex == 2 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1].Value != null)

    {

        DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1]);

    }

    else if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].ColumnIndex == 3 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value != null)

    {

        DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2]);

    }

    else

        MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}



private void cncInfoDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)

{

    //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.

    //make sure user select only single cell

    //and the cell have a value in it

    if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value != null)

    {

        DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);

    }

    else if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == 2 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1].Value != null)

    {

        DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1]);

    }

    else if (cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].ColumnIndex == 3 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2].Value != null)

    {

        DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[2]);

    }

    else

      MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error   uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

}

        }

    }

}
```

} }

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24804259/upload-and-download-button-not-working-for-third-columncells-and-fourth-column/24815055?noredirect=1#comment38553151_24815055

Comment: And strangely enough, the question was asked by user3846692 and answered by Milan phir.

Answer (score 1):

One issue that I see here is with those conditions:

```
cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[1].ColumnIndex == 2
```

If You expect that only a single cell is selected (`SelectedCells.Count == 1`), then there will be no `SelectedCells[1]`, or `SelectedCells[2]`, etc... There's always `SelectedCells[0]`.

So, just use `SelectedCells[0]` in every place where You want to refer to the selected cell (as You only want a single cell selected).

**edit**: As an aside I suggest You clean up Your code a little bit by writing a function like below:

```
private bool SelectedNonNullCellFromColumn(int columnId)
{
    return cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && 
            cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == columnId 
            && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value != null
}
```

and then using in all Your conditions like this:

```
if(SelectedNonNullCellFromColumn(1))
{
    DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);
}
```

(conditions for upload are somewhat different as they don't check against null value so You can create a similar function for those)

**edit2** Actually, You don't event need that. After fixing original issue, all those `Download()`, `Upload()` inside conditions will always act on `SelectedCells[0]` So You can merge all Your conditions into one like:

```
//just write those helper functions
if(SelectedSingleNonNullCell() && SelectedCellColumn() > 3)
{
     DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);
}
```

Comment: @Gregorz Slawexki I edited as per you said. Now upload and downlaod button working. But the problem is every attachment getting uploaded to the 2nd column <http://i57.tinypic.com/kf13ie.png>

Comment: Please any one reply me. i am waiting for an answer. i need reply. :-(

Comment: May be i have a doubt. I have created a local database called data.cnf and i am trying to create a data base in form too.May be because of that its giving out the error

Comment: See when i gave your helper function its giving me an error `private void SelectedNonNullCellFromColumn(int columnId)
{
    return cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells.Count == 1 && 
            cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex == columnId 
            && cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0].Value != null
}` Error is : `SelectedNonNullCellFromColumn(int)' returns void, a return keyword must not be followed by an object expression 
`. Please let me know

Comment: Here You go: `private bool` instead of `private void`.

Comment: that was perfect my error went. Now when i wrote the other function you said `private void btnDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      //Throw error if attachment cell is not selected.
      //make sure user select only single cell
      //and the cell have a value in it
      if (SelectedSingleNonNullCell() && SelectedCellColumn() > 3)
        {
         DownloadAttachment(cncInfoDataGridView.SelectedCells[0]);
         }
        else
  MessageBox.Show("Select a single cell from Attachment column", "Error uploading file", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }`

Comment: It is showing me the error `The name 'SelectedSingleNonNullCell' and 'SelectedCellColumn' does not exist in the current context. SO what to do in this situation

Comment: u r there... What to do with the 'SelectedSingleNonNullCell' and 'SelectedCellColumn' does not exist in the current context.